# I can't get MongoDB to work in vs code on my mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-catalina

I am fairly new to coding and have used mongodb on a cloud IDE but would like to use on my computer instead but I can't get it to work.

Where am I going wrong?

I have a mac and I am working in vs code.

I have read many articles on here about this problem and tried some of the solutions if not all that I have found, read the docs, watched YouTube videos and have not been able to get mongoDB to run in vs code.

I have also installed the extension on vs code and looked at their docs. (could also use how to open a playground as well)

I also have installed homebrew and it is also in the same place as mongodb usr/local file

Here are some photos of where mongodb is and the errors in my terminal
would really appreciate some help.

```
mongod --dbpath=/data
bash: mongod: command not found

<mongodb-install-directory>/bin
bash: mongodb-install-directory: No such file or directory

brew services start mongodb
bash: brew: command not found

/usr/local/mongodb
bash: /usr/local/mongodb: is a directory
 mongod
bash: mongod: command not found

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
mongod
bash: mongod: command not found
```

[where files are[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DirD3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's better to use homebrew https://brew.sh/ to install and manage applications on a mac. First thing is to install homebrew and ensure it's properly installed using brew -v(returns the version that was installed). Then https://www.robinwieruch.de/mongodb-macos-setup should guide on installing mongodb and getting it up and running. If any errors occur, just copy and paste them on google and try out solutions from there. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

got it working, had to uninstall homebrew and reinstall it first. I am not sure why but I saw it on another post and that worked.